# ¿Qué otra opción hay si no se puede ejecutar un .appendChild en una variable donde se ha utilizado .getElementsByClassName?

Tags: javascript

En un archivo javascript creo una variable

```
let containerCart = document.getElementsByClassName('contPRS');
```

y aparte tengo una función donde guardo en un objeto unos valores obtenidos del id de un elemento y luego creo otra variable y en esta luego de crear un elemento y poner unas líneas de html mediante el .innerHTML() como se describe posteriormente en el código

```
 const row = document.createElement('div');
 row.classList.add('product');
 row.innerHTML = 
                 `<div class="imagen">
                     <img src="${image}" alt="${name}">
                 </div>
                 <div class="info">
                     <h4 id="nombrePR">${name}</h4>
                 </div>
                 <div class="eliminar">
                     <i class="icon-trash-empty" data-cod="${cod}"></i>
                 </div>`;
```

intento agregar un appendChild a la variable containerCart y en la consola cuando ejecuto el script me envía un mensaje de `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'appendChild')` y en otra pág web me indica que una solución puede ser accediendo al containerCart en la posición 0 para poder utilizar el `.appendChild`, es decir, `containerBuyCart[0].appendChild(row);` ; ya lo intenté y de igual manera me saltó el mismo TypeError mencionado. En otro apartado me dice que haga una condicional para validar que el valor sea un objeto y que contenga la propiedad appendChild antes de llamar al método, lo cuál me dejo sin comprender la solución que quiere mostrar porque a la variable que esta relacionada con el `getElementsByClassName()` le da un valor de null para luego realizar la condicional.

el link de la página deonde encontre todo lo mencionado anteriormente es: [https://bobbyhadz.com/blog/javascript-typeerror-appendchild-is-not-a-function#:~:text=The%20%22appendChild%20is%20not%20a,misspelling%20appendChild%20%2D%20it's%20case%20sensitive](https://bobbyhadz.com/blog/javascript-typeerror-appendchild-is-not-a-function#:%7E:text=The%20%22appendChild%20is%20not%20a,misspelling%20appendChild%20%2D%20it%27s%20case%20sensitive).

y la imagen de la última solución es:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Alguien me puede ayudar a comprender esta parte o si tienen otra solución para este tipo de errores que me puedan compartir, le agradezco de antemano**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[document.getElementsByClassName()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) te devuelve una [colección HTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection) y no puedes manipularla directamente, por eso es que debes acceder a cada elemento por su índice y, como estás obteniendo solo uno, el índice es cero: `[0]`

Si no te ha funcionado, probablemente la colección esta vacía porque no se encontró un elemento que tenga la clase especificada.

```js
// Este elemento sí existe
let containerCart = document.getElementsByClassName('contPRS');

const row = document.createElement('div');
row.classList.add('product');
row.innerHTML = 
                 `<div class="imagen">
                     Aquí la imagen
                 </div>
                 <div class="info">
                     <h4 id="nombrePR">Nombre delproducto</h4>
                 </div>
                 <div class="eliminar">
                     <i class="icon-trash-empty" data-cod="codigo">Eliminar</i>
                 </div>`;

// Puedes agregar contenido especificando índice
containerCart[0].appendChild(row);

// Este otro no existe
let containerOther = document.getElementsByClassName('no-existe');
// Va a generar error
containerOther[0].appendChild(row);
```

```html
<div class="contPRS"></div>
```

Ahora, si tienes solo un contenedor, puedes obtenerlo con [document.querySelector()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector), que devuelve solo un elemento que cumpla con el selector especificado.

- Si lo quieres por id, agrega `#` al inicio
- Si lo quieres por clase, agrega `.` al inicio

```js
// Este elemento sí existe y se selecciona por clase
let containerCart = document.querySelector('.contPRS');

const row = document.createElement('div');
row.classList.add('product');
row.innerHTML = 
                 `<div class="imagen">
                     Aquí la imagen
                 </div>
                 <div class="info">
                     <h4 id="nombrePR">Nombre delproducto</h4>
                 </div>
                 <div class="eliminar">
                     <i class="icon-trash-empty" data-cod="codigo">Eliminar</i>
                 </div>`;

// No se necesita índice, porque es un solo elemento, no una colección
containerCart.appendChild(row);

// Este otro no existe
let containerOther = document.querySelector('.no-existe');
// Va a generar error
containerOther.appendChild(row);
```

```html
<div class="contPRS"></div>
```

Comment: Gracias por tu explicación @Triby. De hecho en el código lo cambie por el ``querySelector()`` y si me funciono como lo esperaba.